# how to acess value of a extern variable within multiple header files

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, linker-errors, header-files

I have 2 header files, login.h and inmenu.h. login.h has included inmenu.h as well.

Now login.h defines an external variable extern char *password_login which is in a var.h header file as

```
printf("Enter the password: \n");
char *password_login = (char *)calloc(MAX, sizeof(char));
scanf("%1000s", password_login);
```

After that when i call inmenu() function from inmenu header file and try to access password_login value

```
char *tmpsqluppass = concatsqluppass(password_login, newpass);
```

This fails saying undefined reference to password_login

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKZpQvi.o: warning: relocation against `password_login' in read-only section` .text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKZpQvi.o: in function `inmenu': /home/legacy/Documents/project/src/../include/inmenu.h:27: undefined reference to` password_login'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This error goes away when i re-declare char *password_login in inmenu.h

But then segmentation fault occurs as the original value of password_login from login.h is lost and password_login points to 0x0 memory address and i use strcat() to concatenate password_login to another string.

How do i retain the value of password_login pointer in inmenu from login.

this is the concatsqluppass function

```
char *concatsqluppass(char *tmppass, char *tmppassnew)
{
    char *sql;
    sql = (char *)calloc(MAX, sizeof(char));
    strcat(sql, "update user_list set encpass = '");
    strcat(sql, tmppassnew);
    strcat(sql, "'");
    strcat(sql, " where encpass = '");
    strcat(sql, tmppass);
    strcat(sql, "'");
    strcat(sql, "\0");
    printf("query to be passed, \"%s\"", sql);
    return sql;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There’s a difference between *declaring* a variable and *defining* a variable. A variable can be declared at least once (but more is allowed). A variable can be defined once and only once.
When you do `extern int x` you are declaring a variable. This says “this variable exists. I didn’t make it, someone else did. Just letting you know it exists“.
When you do `int x` you are declaring *and* defining a variable. This says “I just made this variable. I created memory for it to live in. It exists. If you can see this statement you can use this variable”

If you put a definition (`int x`) in a header, chances are you’ll define a variable more than once, as multiple files will `#include` that file.
This is why you should put the definition (`int x`) in the cpp file, as noone should `#include` a cpp. If other files need to also use the variable, a declaration (`extern int x`) can also go in the header file.

Doing this, you can put `extern char *password_login` in as many headers as you want and use the variable on those files.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. If i define the variables it in the main c file(char *password_login;) that includes the headers, then should i just declare "extern char *password_login;" in the headers ? Thanks for the claridication.

Comment: `int x;` outside a function is a *tentative definition* in C, and the C standard leaves what happens if there are multiple tentative definitions up to implementations. Until recently, GCC coalesced tentative definitions, in accordance with long-standing Unix tools behavior. It is still selectable with the `-fcommon` switch.

Answer (score 0):

define password in login object file and define that same variable in imenu object file as

```
extern char * password_login
...
...
function(password_login,...);
```

make sure to use object file rather than writing code in header files.

Comment: Should i just compile the login and inmenu as object files and link them after ?